# How to avoid ^M character in unix shell script..?

Tags: linux, shell, maven, unix

I am trying to generate shutdown.sh file using appassembler-maven-plugin with the below template

```
#!/bin/sh
@LICENSE_HEADER@
@ENV_SETUP@

kill -1 $(cat ./samp.pid)
```

The sh file is generated as below.

```
#!/bin/sh
#   ====================================================================
#   Organization            : Sample Software JLT
#   Copyright (c) 2012
#   ====================================================================

kill -1 $(cat ./aqua.pid)
```

But,when i try to open it in linux vi editor i am getting ^M character at every end of line.How to avoid it.

I am using the below plugin to generate the sh file

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Aqua-Shutdown</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
            <configurationDirectory>aqua/config</configurationDirectory>                <includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>true</includeConfigurationDirectoryInClasspath>
                        <showConsoleWindow>false</showConsoleWindow>
                        <platforms>
                            <platform>windows</platform>
                            <platform>unix</platform>
                        </platforms>    
                        <binFileExtensions>
                            <unix>.sh</unix>
                        </binFileExtensions>
                        <unixScriptTemplate>${basedir}/template/unixShutdownScriptTemplate</unixScriptTemplate>         <windowsScriptTemplate>${basedir}/template/windowScriptTemplate</windowsScriptTemplate>
                        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                        <useAsterikClassPath>true</useAsterikClassPath>
                        <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
                <assembleDirectory>target/assembleDir</assembleDirectory>
                        <repositoryName>samp/dependencies</repositoryName>
                        <programs>
                            <program>
                                    <mainClass>com.samp.aqua.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent</mainClass>
                                <name>shutdown</name>
                                <commandLineArguments>
                    <commandLineArgument>SHUTDOWN</commandLineArgument>
                                </commandLineArguments>
                            </program>
                        </programs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: `^M CR 0x0d  13 CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)` - Microsoft's new line is `\r\n` or `CARRIAGE RETURN` `NEW LINE` whereas Unix just uses `\n`.

Comment: If you write the file in DOS systems you are likely to have such ^M. You can "clean" the file by running `dos2unix` against it.

Comment: What kind of shutdown script are you trying to implement. Are you using deamon or what in appassembler-maven-plugin ? Or using JSW ?

Comment: Thank you for replay..
i am using appassembler-maven-plugin with the above configuration.

Comment: That wasn't what i asked for. I know that you are using appassembly-maven-plugin....Furthermore why are you using such an ancient version ? See [here for the uptodate information](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/). Maybe the JSW is a better choice for your where you already have such things...

Answer (score 0):

You ask how to avoid this situation.

Well ... this is not really a programming question, but anyway, the solution is easy: When creating a new file, use a text editor which can be told to use unix-line endings instead of Windows ones. Most editors can do this, but a few don't offer this feature.

When opening an old file, many editors continue to use the line ending style which is already there, but nearly all of them offer the possibility to convert the endings. Of course, another way to do it is to use `dos2unix`, as @fedorqui has recommended.

Since most of the Windows programs nowadays can process files with \n line endings, I keep the habit to always use this line ending style only, except when I know for sure that I need a different line ending style for a certain application.

You didn't tell us about your development environment, and there is one thing you need to be careful about:

Another source of \r\n line endings could be your version control system (Clearcase, Subversion, Git,....). Most of these can be configured to "fix" line endings when checking in the file from a Windows host, and even if they are configured in this way and you create a text file with Unix endings, it might be silently turned into one with Windows endings, when you check it in under Windows. If this is the case, you need to bypass this "fix".